# return pointer rather than vector::iterator and convert vector::iterator to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

i have a function that its return type is "vector::iterator" in below:

```
vector<unsigned int>::iterator foo(unsigned int arg, vector<unsigned int> arr, vector<unsigned int> M)
{    if (arg == 0)
        return arr.begin();
    else if (arg == 2)
        return arr.begin() + arr[arg - 1];
    else
        return arr.begin();
}
```

the question is this, how to convert its return value to a pointer rather than of std::vector iterator?

i should be convert it for use to kernel in CUDA because we couldn't use vector or its iterator in CUDA

This is my way:

```
__host__ __device__ unsigned int* foo(unsigned int arg, unsigned int* arr, unsigned int* M)
{  
    unsigned int* res, tmp;
    if (arg == 0)
        tmp = arr[0];
    else if (arg == 2)
        tmp = arr[0] + arr[arg - 1];
    else
        tmp = arr[0];
        res = &tmp;
    return res; 
}
```

for work in kernel, for example:

```
__global__ kernel void kernel . . .
.
.
unsigned int* d_h = foo( , ,)
.
.
```

but it's wrong and doesn't work, how to could i do it? Thanks,

Comment: Your first function is already wrong, since you are returning an iterator from a copied vector, the iterator is invalidated as soon the function returns.

Comment: `tmp = arr[0];` and the following assignments to `tmp` are wrong. You probably want to take the address: `tmp = &arr[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If with converting you mean rewriting the code without using vectors, but using arrays instead, I'd propose the following adjustments to your code:

```
__host__ __device__ unsigned int* foo(unsigned int arg, unsigned int* arr, unsigned int* M)
{  
    unsigned int *res, *tmp;  // attention * is per item !! 
    if (arg == 0)
        tmp = arr;  // return a pointer to the begining
    else if (arg == 2)
        tmp = arr + arr[arg - 1];  // you need to make pointer arithmetic like in the original code iterator arithmetics
    else
        tmp = arr;  // keep it simple 
    return tmp;    // note that you don't need res. 
}
```

The main issue in your code was that  declaration `unsigned int *a,b;` creates a pointer `a` to an `unsigned int` and an `unsigned int` variable `b`, but not two pointers.

The second issue was the line  `res = &tmp;` (*by the way, its indenting is misleading. Fortunately [gcc 6 will warn you in future](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GCC6-Misleading-Indentation)*). This caused you to return the address of a temporary variable. But a temporary variable is destroyed as soon as you return from the function, so your returned pointer will point to a nowhere place (UB in perspective).

Comment: Cheers!  My problem was solved!  So Thank you for help me, i used @Christophe solution, it dose work properly as i wanted! Thanks you again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do `&(*it)` which will provide a pointer to the element that the iterator refers to. Use `std::addressof(*it)` in generic code over `std::vector<T>` if you don't know if `operator&` has been overloaded by evil users.

Answer (score 1):

You can in principle use `&*i` to get a pointer to the iterator's element, and hence the underlying vector data, but that won't help you here.

Your first function is broken, as it returns an iterator into a vector whose lifetime ends when the function returns.

To fix that, you could take the vector by reference,

```
vector<unsigned int>::iterator foo(unsigned int arg, vector<unsigned int>& arr)
{
    return arg == 2 ? arr.begin() + arr[1] : arr.begin();
}
```

but indexing is more robust than iterating and behaves well with const-ness:

```
int foo(unsigned int arg, const vector<unsigned int>& arr)
{
    return arg == 2 ? arr[1] : 0;
}

vector<unsigned int>::iterator it = myvector.begin() + foo(arg, myvector);
vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator cit = myvector.cbegin() + foo(arg, myvector);
```

(Iterators are for *iterating* – they're meant to be transient and short-lived.
You shouldn't use them as a kind of generalised pointer.)

The CUDA code returns an equally wrong pointer to an automatic local variable when it should return a pointer into `arr`:

```
__host__ __device__ unsigned int* foo(unsigned int arg, unsigned int* arr, unsigned int* M)
{
    return arg == 2 ? arr + arr[1] : arr;  
}
```